# List in a table

Tags: tables

I am creating a table with two columns. One of the column has a list in it. Following is the  code.

```
\begin{table}[] 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Research Questions} \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Flower Specification \\and Interpretation~~~\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l@{}}What are the different types of Flowers?\\ What are the different fragrances to express or define the flowers?\\ What are the different flower plantation methods?\\ What are various attributes a flower can have?\\ What are various steps and methods/techniques to grow a flower into a hostile (extreme cold or hot) weather?\end{tabular} \\ \hline     
\end{tabular}}  
\end{table}
```

1. I want to change the dotted list to numbered list.
2. I want to break the 'question 5' into two lines while keeping the list structure (attached is the expected table.[image])

Comment: only use `\resizebox` on tables as a last resort (and even then avoid doing it) also `\centering` in `\resizebox` does nothing at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of `enumitem` for the numbered list and `tabularx` for a table whose column width automatically adjusts to the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}

% only used for second example:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.25cm}|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Research Questions} \\ \hline
        Flower Specification and Interpretation 
        & \begin{tabenum}
        \item What are the different types of Flowers?
        \item What are the different fragrances to express or define the flowers?
        \item What are the different flower plantation methods?
        \item What are various attributes a flower can have?
        \item What are various steps and methods/techniques to grow a flower into a hostile (extreme cold or hot) weather?
        \end{tabenum} \\ \hline     
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.25cm}X}
        \toprule
        Activity & Research Questions \\ \midrule
        Flower Specification and Interpretation 
        & \begin{tabenum}
        \item What are the different types of Flowers?
        \item What are the different fragrances to express or define the flowers?
        \item What are the different flower plantation methods?
        \item What are various attributes a flower can have?
        \item What are various steps and methods/techniques to grow a flower into a hostile (extreme cold or hot) weather?
        \end{tabenum} \\ \bottomrule     
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How to bring the text of first column in the center of the cell? How to keep the font size same of both columns?

Comment: Do you want to vertically center the contents of the first column? If so, remove the `[t]` from `before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}` and use an `m` instead of  a `p` type column (`\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.25cm}|X|}`). If you want to horizontally center the contens, keep the `[t]` and use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.25cm}|X|}`. Regarding the font size: I can't see a difference in font sized if I compare both columns.

Comment: Sorry it is the typo.

Answer (score 1):

What about this. Note that in order to get number 5 in 2 rows i had to set the table width to 1.2 of `\textwidth`. You should change it to just `\textwidth` but than you have 3 rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|X|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Research question}  \\ \hline
            Flower specification and Interpretation & \vspace{-6mm}\begin{enumerate} \item What are the different types of Flowers? \item What are the different fragrances to express or define the flowers? \item What are the different flower plantation methods? \item What are various attributes a flower can have? \item What are various steps and methods/techniques to grow a flower into a hostile (extreme cold or hot) weather? \end{enumerate} \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]